# How can I enable local desktop-directories?

Tags: gnome, appmenu, menulibre

I have a GNOME desktop-directory (aka appfolder) defined at `/usr/share/desktop-directories/X-GNOME-Utilities.directory` This functions as expected in the Ubuntu application menu, grouping all applications defined under it.

I have other desktop-directory files in `$HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/` generated by [Menu Editor](https://github.com/bluesabre/menulibre) (aka `menulibre`) but they are not honored. How do I enable them?

Answer (score 1):

How can I enable local desktop-directories?
[How can I enable local desktop-directories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1448229/1694462?sem=2)

I already have the same problem as you. I got a bunch of app-icons on the dock. A long time ago I could gather them together. However, since I modified my home path the approach is invalid. Once I restart the desktop-directory disappears. I feel confused about that. Today I found a nice method to solve this problem.

Follow the doc, I think you can solve your problem too.

https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/AppFolders

[image]

Comment: Hi - it's usually best to write up the solution in your answer rather than link to the solution on a 3rd party site. This is in case that site goes down and your answer becomes useless.